# How to access Plugin Data from Wordpress using Wordpress Rest API

Tags: reactjs, wordpress, wordpress-rest-api

I'm creating a fundraising site similar to gofundme.com using Wordpress. I want to get the data stored from a WP Plugin via WP Rest API using ReactJS, Is there a way to access the data within the Plugin?

Comment: Which plugin? If you go to yourdomain.com/wp-json/wp/v2/ you should see a property called `routes` and, if the plugin has exposed any routes, they will be here. But the plugin does need to make the data accessible via the API (or you need to)

Comment: any donation plugin or the event manager plugin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update: I use a plugin called Wordpress Rest API Controller to access other endpoints

here's a link to [Wordpress API Controller Plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-rest-api-controller/)

Edit: Note all endpoints are open when using the plugin. the only option that I know is to create a custom endpoint